# GWT RequestFactory can not update object graph

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

At my client side the code like this:

```
@ProxyFor(...)
public interface AProxy
{
  BProxy getChild();
  void setChild(BPorxy child);
}

RequestContext ctx=...
AProxy parent=...
AProxy a=ctx.edit(parent);
a.getChild().setContent("new content");//update content
ctx.save(a).fire();
```

From the browser debug console i can see the request is sent to server with the updated new content, but from server side's `save(A a)` method, the content of child b is the same as before(never changed), but other update in  `a` is reflected.

And I use Locator at server side. No problem when creating the entity graph, just can not be updated.

Anyone shed some light on what's the problem here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It must be that you have 2 distinct `B` instances for the "same" entity and/or `setChild` does a copy of its argument.

Set appropriate breakpoints in locators and setters to debug it (pay attention to the object id)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've checked my `B` proxy is correctly set. I forgot to mention my `BProxy` is `EntityProxy`, not `ValueProxy`, I wonder if GWT support updating parent/child EntityProxy object graph at a time?

Comment: It probably depends how your persistence layer is configured. 
How does the `save()` method look like on the backend ? I guess it just calls `em.perrist(a);` ?
If you use `JPA2` you can specify the `cascade` rules (i.e. merge, persist, etc).